# How to only update the data that has changed in QTableView (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyqt5, insert-update

So basically this is my PandasModel:

```
class pandasModel(QAbstractTableModel):

    def __init__(self, data, editable=False):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self)
        self._data = data
        self.editable = editable

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return self._data.shape[0]

    def columnCount(self, parnet=None):
        return self._data.shape[1]

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
                return str(self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()])
            elif role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
                return Qt.AlignCenter

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if role == Qt.EditRole:
            self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()] = value
            return True
        return False

    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data.columns[col]

    def flags(self, index):
        if self.editable:
            return Qt.ItemIsEditable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable
        else:
            return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable
        
    def sort(self, col, order):
        """sort table by given column number col"""
        self.layoutAboutToBeChanged.emit()
        self._data = self._data.sort_values(
            self._data.columns[col], ascending=order == Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.layoutChanged.emit()
```

And this is the way I'm updating my Table when the data is changed and received from the thread using API.
Basically my other Thread runs in a while loop constantly and if the data is changed it emits the new array of data to main thread and then the data is received and that is when the data is changed.

```
self.Table.setModel(pandasModel(self.myDataFrame))
```

I only wanted to update the new data but this updates whole table, due to that the selection is also lost!

Is there other way we can do it so that the values are updated but the table doesn't reset completely and also the selections of rows to be not lost???

P.S. the data is huge so cannot just pick one and update manually I want something dynamic

Comment: you can compare the two dataframes and emit [dataChanged](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged) for the relevant indexes.

Comment: How is the data "changed"? Does the size of the model change, or only the contents? Please improve your question and provide a [mre] that also includes the thread part.

Comment: I have updated! Please tell me if you understand.